# Angular, how to assign controller to markup before ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-controller

Can anyone tell me if is possible to assign a controller from a directive to the markup before ng-repeat does his thing?

The code below is just an example of what i want to do

```
<body ng-app="App">
<div my-t>
  <div ng-repeat="obj in List">
    {{obj.Name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('App',[])
.directive('myT',[function(){
    return {
        replace : true,
        transclude : true,
        template : '<div ng-controller="listCtrl"><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
    };
}])
.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.List = [
        {Name: 'a'},{Name: 'b'}
    ];
}]);
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/weulMrGao0Rd9PUfGTmt?p=preview)

The problem is that when my directive changes the template, assigning the ng-controller the ng-repeat has already compiled and so it will display no data. Moving the ng-controller to the markup it´s not an option.

Best.

Comment: you can put `ng-controller="listCtrl"` on any element parent to your ng-repeat, even on the same element the `ng-app` is on

Comment: Hi @maurycy I explicit need to let the directive insert in the markup what controller is going to use, it is not a matter of where to put it, is a matter of using a directive to put the ng-controller and the ng-repeat will be able to use the list given by the controller. But thanks :)

Comment: You can also put the `controller` to your directive, with `controller: 'listCtrl'`, you can then also remove the `ng-controller` from your template.

Comment: @Chasmo Thanks this resolve the main problem. You can write it as answer and i will marked as the answer.

Comment: @JoseRocha, thanks, did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also put the controller to your directive, with `controller: 'listCtrl'`, you can then also remove the `ng-controller` from your template.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div my-t>
  <div ng-repeat="obj in List">
    {{obj.Name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('App',[])
.directive('myT',[function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace : true,
        transclude : true,
        template : '<div><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        controller : 'listCtrl'
    };
}])
.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.List = [
        {Name: 'a'},{Name: 'b'}
    ];
}]);
```